# Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c RAC

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

We've just provisioned a 2 node Oracle 12c RAC with the help of an outside vendor, and we have very little internal knowledge or experience of Oracle (2 guys used to use Oracle 9i elsewhere).

I've been asked to setup Enterprise Manager to make the system easier to administer and monitor by our Service Desk as I've used Enterprise Manager on an 11g database at my previous employment.

So, here I am, researching and investigating and being baffled by what's required as far as Enterprise Manager which has moved on from Grid Control to Cloud Control, and is now supposed to be installed onto a separate server to either of the RAC nodes, and do I need to install Web Logic server etc.

I have a separate server ready to go, could someone give me some guidance on what exactly I need to install and in what ordert so we have a console that can administer this and any future Oracle systems we roll out.

Appreciate any and all replies.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Enterprise Manager transition from Grid Control to Cloud Control was done to make the enterprise monitoring functionality more robust.  The transition allowed them to incorporate more Oracle products into the suite through various licenses and updates, and also add more flexibility in reporting (through the addition of BI Publisher addons) and custom monitoring (via metric extensions).  The Incident Management suite has also been completely revamped.

Aside from that, the installation is fairly straightforward, especially when concerning an Oracle RAC as it's primary repository.  The new version of OEM sits as an application layer on top of an Oracle Web Logic cluster.  What this means is that the installation INCLUDES Web Logic.  It is not necessary to install this at all.  The installation will build a Web Logic cluster based on the high availability configuration you choose during setup and will point to the repository you choose.

Upon installation, you can access OEM in the method that is described during installation.  You will also see a Web logic console access URL that allows you to manipulate and configure the backend WebLogic instance that runs the application.  If you are not very familiar with the architecture, I would leave the WebLogic portion alone.

I would suggest using blogs or videos of actual customers running the installation.  The Oracle Documentation is robust, but can also be very cumbersome.  Without knowing your full environment (Linux version, Windows version, etc?) I wouldn't be able to provide direct assistance.  Here is an example of a solid installation guide:

[OEM Installation](https://blog.rackspace.com/install-and-configure-oracle-enterprise-manager-cloud-control-12c)

Comment: Thank you Chris, really appreciate your response, I'll have a loo at the link you sent.  Does this mean I can just install the OEM on one of the cluster nodes?  They're Windows servers by the way in case that changes anything in your assessment.

Comment: I have successfully done installations on Linux with both versions of the configuration:  One server with the repository and the OEM instance running.  I have also done a High Availability configuration with a RAC repository on 2 separate servers, and an OEM installation with 2 HA instances on 2 additional servers.  Both worked fine.  If you do decide to install OEM on the same server as the repository, I would still recommend doing an HA configuration and putting an instance on each of the 2 RAC nodes.

Comment: Windows should fall under the same architecture, so that should not be a concern in regards to installation.